# You cannot initiate a RDC because Windows logon software been replaced remgina.dll

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003

I cannot RDC to the server after a server 2003 in-place upgrade has been done. See picture.
[image]

Comment: How about some details? What did you upgrade to? It's not clear from your question. What version RDP client are you connecting with?

Comment: I'm not having any luck figuring out what third-party application uses REMGINA.DLL. Anybody know? If you've got the REMGINA.DLL file it would be interesting to see if it bears any manufacturer information.

Comment: What's your question? All you've done so far is made a statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick google failed to turn up anything, so I turn it over to you, @IT_Fixr: do you have a replacement remote desktop software installed? How about a third-party VPN solution? A VNC server? Basically, `remgina.dll` replaces the normal logon procedures in Windows so something special can work. From the looks of various forums, this was part of a particular product circa early 2000s that was abandoned by the author 2003 or thereabouts. I must confess I'm a little curious as to what this product was.

If you remove the entry from the registry, the software that required this replacement will now fail. Of course, something that hasn't been updated in a decade is probably not something you'll be immediately missing. But I'd always want to find the cause of a problem, not just stop it from happening.

Answer (score 0):

Start/Run/Regedit 
HKEY LOCAL MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\Current 
Version\WinLogon. In the right pane, remove the entry for 
remgina.DLL and Reboot

Comment: This will work, but it would be best to figure out *why* the GINA has been replaced before just cutting it out.